# Print PG Result Object in Rails Console

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I am doing some basic SQL queries in my rails console. When I query my postgreSQL database, the result is a PG Result object as seen here:

```
#<PG::Result:0x007f26cac82010 status=PGRES_TUPLES_OK ntuples=1 nfields=1 cmd_tuples=1>
```

My query looks like the following:

```
sql = "SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT Business_id) FROM applications"
result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
```

I'm currently doing a basic COUNT query and I would like to see the count result.

How can I view the data inside of the PG Result object?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The PGResult object has some special methods for retrieving the results, the 'getvalue' method returns the tuple n as a hash, so then you could do:

```
result.getvalue(0,0)
```

More detailed information can be found here here:

http://deveiate.org/code/pg/PG/Result.html

Comment: result.inspect returns the same object (PG::Result)

Comment: I found this: http://deveiate.org/code/pg/PG/Result.html. Does the 'getvalue' method work?

Comment: getvalue(0,0) did end up working. If you modify your answer I will mark as correct. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 30):

```
result.values
```

will print a multidimensional array of the results